# Stop jQuery function from running on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, pageload

I am having the following problem. Below is a summarized code

```
function submitProfileForm() {            

    console.log('here');
}

$(function () {

    //save function
    $('.save').on('click', function(){

        $('form.Zebra_Form').parsley().validate();
        return submitProfileForm();
    });

    //profile form validation
    $('form.Zebra_Form').on('submit', submitProfileForm());
});
```

On page load, the submitProfileForm() function is run immediately the page loads while it should only run when either, the Zebra Form is submitted or when an external save button is clicked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Zebra_Form is the css class of the form tag?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass function `submitProfileForm` as a parameter on `on('submit',func)`

```
$('form.Zebra_Form').on('submit', submitProfileForm);
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are calling it in here `$('form.Zebra_Form').on('submit', submitProfileForm());`. Look into `submitProfileForm()` part. You should pass the function as paramter